# compositeData object in xpages

Tags: custom-controls, lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino

I am working on a custom control and have created a property in property definition section.
I can see this property under compositeData global object whenever i go to write SSJS anywhere in this custom control. But if I go to any other custom control or in the xpage that contains this custom control I am not able to see this property under compositeData global object section. Actually I want to change the value of this property on click of a button which exists in some other custom control. Please suggest me some way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compositeDate properties are only available within the custom control itself. You can choose to transfer the properties to the custom control using e.g. a viewScope variable or a dataContext. Thereby you can change/calculate/refresh the property which is passed to the custom control.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Goto Xpage, Where you have embedded the custom control?
 2. Give the id to custom control.
 3. Goto its All property option, There you can find the values of compositeData.
 4. Here we can change the value of cc property with the use of cc's id.
```

Answer (score 0):

What is compositeData inside the custom control are the custom properties where it is used. Click the embedded custom control, then open the Custom Properties tab.

If you want to change a custom property's value dynamically, you have to pass a computed value (e.g. based on a scoped variable)..